# i want to create account record using batch class

Tags: apex, batch

need yur help to create account record using batch class,,

```
global class batchClass implements Database.batchable<sObject>{ 
    public String query;

       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

          return Database.getQueryLocator(Query); 
         }   
       global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<Account> scope){
           Account accsToUpdate=new Account(Name='ssa');
           insert accsToUpdate; 
       }     
       global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){     
       } 

}
```

i started like this,i know it is wrong, please tell me what to do,

Comment: you want to create account using batch class. so what is the Query ?

Comment: i tired with the abovre code,,,record not created,,i want to know what is the problem there

Comment: How are you executing this batch class ?

Comment: from developer console

Comment: batchClass    bulkupdate=  new   batchClass ();
database.executeBatch(bulkupdate);

Comment: You are not passing any query, Hence scope for the execute batch will be empty. Hence no account records are created.

Comment: how to pass that query,,can i achieve,,can u please guide,,to create new records,how can i pass query,,

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any records to use, you can use an iterable instead. Here's an iterable-based example:

```
public class CreateAccounts implements Database.Batchable<String> {
  public String[] start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return new String[] { 'ssa' };
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, String[] scope) {
    Account[] records = new Account[0];
    for(String accountName: scope) {
      records.add(new Account(Name=accountName));
    }
    insert records;
  }
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
  }
}
```

It's up to you to determine what the appropriate data structure would look like. The main point is that a query is not the only way to kick off a batchable process.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Salesforce Doc for for execution of batch class [Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)

```
global class CreateAccountRecordsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

   global final String Query;
   global CreateAccountRecordsBatch(String q){
        Query=q;
   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
     List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
     for(Account acc : scope){
        Account objA = new Account(Name = acc.Name);
        accountList.add(objA);
     }
     insert accountList;
    }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   }
}


//Execute Batch class from developer console
// Query for 10 accounts
String q = 'SELECT Id, Name, Industry FROM Account LIMIT 10';

Id batchInstanceId = Database.executeBatch(new CreateAccountRecordsBatch(q), 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the sample code, by which you can create records by batch class.

```
global class InsertAccountContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

     global InsertAccountContact(){
                // Batch Constructor
     }

     // Start Method
     global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
     // Generate your string query on any object here with limit 10000
     String Query = 'select id,name from account limit 2';
     //Query is Required on object which you want to run Batch
     return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
     }

   // Execute Logic
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject>objlist){
    system.debug('>>>>>>execute>>>>>'+objlist);
        List<Account> acclist = new List<Account>();
        list<Contact> conlist = new list<contact>();
          for(Sobject obj: objlist){
                Account acc = new account();
                acc.name = 'Account_CreatedByBatchClass';
                acclist.add(acc);
          }
       insert acclist;
    for(Account acc : Acclist){
          Contact con = new Contact();
           con.lastname = 'Contact_CreatedByBatchClass';
           con.accountid = acc.id;
           conlist.add(con);
   }  
   Insert conlist;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
         // Logic to be Executed at finish
    }
 }
```